# GIT Head-> <mi branch>, origin/main, main

Tags: git, main, originmain

En un proyecto hice un checkout a 2 commit anteriores (para practicar) y al hacer un git status me aparecio el famoso HEAD DETACHED, por lo cual volvi a hacer un git checkout al ultimo commit, luego un git checkout main, posteriormente cree una nueva rama y finalmente las ramas me quedaron acorde a la imagen.

Mi pregunta es: que deberia haber hecho para evitar el detached?, y por otro lado, que significa el orden siguient orden en el ultimo commit, tanto de mi rama main, como la nueva rama spring-booot-data-jpa? Head -> , origin/master / main?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esa imagen seria mejor reemplazarla por texto en la pregunta.

Comment: Por favor, ponlo _como texto_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976), además, si lo haces, tu pregunta será más sencilla de encontrar para aquellos que lleguen a tener un problema similar.

Answer (score 2):

No tienes nada que temer de quedar en `detached HEAD`. Como le pediste a git hacer el checkout de un commit (en vez de una rama), entonces git te pone en él *sin estar en una rama*, cosa que es perfectamente normal. Luego puedes, para regresar, hacer un checkout de la rama en la que estabas (o alguna otra) y sales del `detached HEAD`.

Quedar en ese estado te va a pasar si pides hacer un checkout de un commit (lo que te sucedió), de una etiqueta, de una rama remota o si pides hacer un checkout con la opción `--detach`. Insisto, nada que temer.

En todo caso, pudiste haber hecho el checkout con una rama, pero es innecesario si lo único que quieres hacer es "mirar" (para hacer unas pruebas, por ejemplo):

```
git checkout -b temporal el-commit-id
# hago lo que necesito.... ahora voy a regresar a donde estaba
git checkout main
git branch -D temporal #borro la rama
```

Perfectamente válido, pero innecesario.

Por último, las ramas que salen en el decoration están indicando que todas están sobre el mismo commit. El orden de las ramas que salen en el *decoration* del log no indica nada. Las ramas son solo apuntadores a commits y no guardan absolutamente ninguna relación entre ellas (a duras penas puedes configurar un upstream para una rama local, y no es información que se guarde en los commits, es algo que queda en el `.git/config`).

Como ñapa voy a explicar que el decoration que dice `HEAD -> main` significa que estás trabajando en la rama `main` (y recuerda que `HEAD` **en git** siempre es donde estás parado).

Comment: Mil gracias! Ahora bien que me hubieses recomendado para salir de ese detached? Disculpa no me quedo claro si lo mejor es crear rama temporal con el commit al que quiero ir. Saludos!

Comment: Para salir solo haces checkout de una rama.